# Register variable in ansible and using custom filter in when

Tags: python, loops, ansible

I want to extract file only when particular directory do not exist.I wrote below code to achieve this.

```
- name: check if program already exists.
  shell: ls /tomcats|grep akash
  register: programexists
- name: extract archive
  command: chdir=/tomcats/ /bin/tar xvf  program.tar.gz
  when: programexists.stdout == {{ program }}
```

but this code fails when "akash" directory do not exists as programexits.stdout will be empty in that case.

I wonder if i can create a custom filter  in filter_plugins which checks if directory exists and use the same in play book like

**code for custom filter**

```
__author__ = 'akthakur'
import os
class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Custom filters are loaded by FilterModule objects '''

    def filters(self):
        ''' FilterModule objects return a dict mapping filter names to
            filter functions. '''
        return {
            'directory_exists': self.directory_exists,
        }

    def directory_exists(self,program):
        static_location='/usr/local/tomcats'
        path=os.path.join(static_location,program)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**and use the filter like**

```
- name: extract archive
  command: chdir=/tomcats/ /bin/tar xvf  program.tar.gz
  when: {{ 'akash'|directory_exists }}
```

I may be expecting too much from ansible but if some one can help me...i will be really thankful.

Answer (score 2):

A custom filter would be overkill. There is an `ignore_errors` parameter.

```
- name: check if program already exists.
  shell: ls /tomcats|grep akash
  register: programexists
  ignore_errors: True
  always_run: True
  changed_when: False

- name: extract archive
  command: chdir=/tomcats/ /bin/tar xvf  program.tar.gz
  when: programexists.stdout == {{ program }}
```

It may also be better to use `programexists.rc == 0` as the condition, in which case the command can become simply `ls /tomcats/akash`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be even simpler. The `command` module has a `creates` parameter, which is nothing but a filter and only will execute the command if the path given to `creates` does not exist. So if your command will create `/tomcats/akash` this should work:

```
- name: extract archive
  command: chdir=/tomcats/ /bin/tar xvf  program.tar.gz
  creates: /tomcats/akash
```

Comment: its nice to use above method but is there any way to use filters in playbooks as i need to again perform some function using file module when a particular directory do not exists.

Comment: Yes it is. Though... the file module as well has the creates parameter. (I think. On phone right now... checked, no it has not :-) )

Comment: @thinkingmonster Actually the correct way would be to create the directory using `file`, then perform the other function using `file`. When using `file` and `command` you should not normally need to use the trick I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the riginal goal there is an 'unarchive' module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html). You can use it like this:

```
- name: unarchive if it does not exist
  unarchive: >
     src=program.tar.gz
     dest=/tomcats/
     creates=/tomcats/
```

The last parameter will check whether the directory exists and will skip the command if yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntax issues in the when condition.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
- name: Check if program already exists
  command: ls /tomcats | grep akash
  register: programexists
  changed_when: false  # Do not mark the task as changed based on the output

- name: Extract archive
  command: tar xvf /tomcats/program.tar.gz -C /tomcats/
  args:
    chdir: /tomcats/
  when: "'{{ program }}' not in programexists.stdout_lines"
```